# Inside out and backwards - more than a question of underwear....

Tags: general-topology

While I am not a mathematician, I find a fascination for motion and 3D space. Lately this idea keeps turning over.
Each time I put my underwear on and find the back label correctly in back but find the pants are inside out ( or vice verse) I watch the process of turning them back to inside in but the label now appears on the front, of course I simply turn them 180 but am continuously intrigued by the concept. I wonder if there is a more involved application or implication than one's getting outfitted for the day.